# current_page is working with locale parameters but is not working without them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm assigning active class to navigation menus using `current_page`, but I don't think I understand how `current_page` works.

Sample codes are as follows.

#### home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def menu
  end
end
```

#### application.html.erb

```
<%= current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'menu').to_s %>

<li><%= link_to(t('menu.title'), {controller: 'home', action: 'menu'}, class: current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'menu')? 'active': '') %></li>
```

When in `localhost:3000/menu`, `application.html.erb` prints false.

When in `localhost:3000/menu?locale=en`, `application.html.erb` prints true.

When in `localhost:3000/menu?locale=ko`, `application.html.erb` also prints true.

I want it to be "active" regardless of `locale` option. According to [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F), what I did should generate the proper result, but it doesn't work as the documentation says.

```
# Let’s say we’re in the http://www.example.com/shop/checkout?order=desc action.

current_page?(action: 'process')
# => false

current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout')
# => true

current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout', order: 'asc')
# => false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across this problem too. I preferred to create my own *current_action?* helper (inside *application_helper.rb*) to check directly with the action, regardless of url params like the *locale* or any other.

Here's the helper I created. Pretty simple:

```
def current_action?(controller: 'default', action: 'default')
    (controller == params[:controller]) and (action == params[:action])
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The rails api reference says that current_page?(options) returns "True if the current request URI was generated by the given options".`

`localhost:3000/menu?locale=en` contains `locale`, which counts as an option used to generate the current request uri. I think `current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'menu', locale: 'en')` returns true.

Comment: Your answer is correct but it's not answering my question. I wanted `current_page` to be true regardless of `locale` option, because in my case where only controller and action determine if a menu is active, `locale` doesn't really matter.

So it seems that there's no way using `current_page` other than workarounds in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried `current_page` for a method which doesn't exist, I found out that `current_page` automatically created an option for `locale`.

#### application.html.erb

```
<%= current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'nothing').to_s %>
```

#### Error

```
# No route matches {:action=>"nothing", :controller=>"home", :locale=>:en}
```

So for now, I think it's best to try something like `current_page?('/menu')` to support various locale options. Because it simply works.